# How to solve "The parameter is incorrect" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, connection-string

How to solve this,
When i run my code it gives error for date?

```
public static DataTable offers(string todaysdate)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Validation.valid_image FROM Validation WHERE (Valid_date <= @today) AND (Valid_Expire >= @today) ", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", todaysdate);
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the actual code and what you have tried in order to solve it yourself. Without it this question will be very quickly closed on it being a "why isn't it working" question

Comment: Avoid adding images to describe your problem. This has the problem of being useless from search point of view besides the fact that external link could becomes unavailable.

Comment: but i dont know wether it is the problem of my connection string it works in vs10 but gives me error in vs12

Comment: @prashantdhuri - so that is also something to write in the question. Please edit your question, add the actual code, show the connection string and say what you have tried. Also add what exactly is the value of the `todaysDate`

Comment: @GiladGreen i have edited

Comment: I am new in this, and don't know asp.net, but in winforms, the parameters don't go between single quotation marks, could that be the problem?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi i have edited this question

Comment: @antonio_veneroso i have tried that but give same error and i think there must be some mistake in connection string...

Answer (score 2):

1.I see your parameter should be @today since your are adding the parameters to sql command with @today as parameter name.

2.But you are using @todya, in the inline sql that why it's throwing the error that parameter is incorrect.

3.I guess you miss spelled change @todya to @today, change @todya to @today to resolve issue.

4.Remove the quotes around @today in inline sql pass as @today instead of '@today' like this and this should fix the issue.

`SELECT Offer_details.Offer_image FROM Offer_details WHERE (Offer_date <=@today) AND (Offer_Expire >=@today)`

5.If you still see issues do below steps 6,7

6.`SELECT Offer_details.Offer_image FROM Offer_details WHERE (Offer_date <='10/06/2016') AND (Offer_Expire >= '10/06/2016')`

7.Run this from SSMS and see if are able to retrieve data,if you are able to then add watch on cmd and see if inline sql is being transformed to appropriate SQL like above or not, if there are any syntax error with additional quotes, remove them.

Comment: i have corrected this error but it didnt work

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: same as the above

Comment: did you remove the quotes around the @today in inline sql?

Comment: Follow the steps inan gave you. If the 6th step don't work, perhaps the problem is your string connection, and probably this site could help you: https://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: @inan yes i did

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove quote (') from query '@today' -> @today I hope this help you.

Comment: thanks but same error i think there must be some error in connection string

Comment: Sorry. Try to debug the portion of code...

Comment: build succeeded

Comment: Yes. Debug during execution. Add a Breakpoint in code behind and than use F10 to scroll.

Comment: it give an error at con